# How to decide that mv moves into a directory rather than replacing directory?

Tags: rename

Say I have a directory `/hello`.

Then I do `mv /hello /hello2`.

Am I moving `/hello` into `/hello2/hello`?
Or am I moving `/hello` to `/hello2`?

It seems that when I do something like this, I get inconsistent results.

Comment: In what case is the result inconsistent? It seems whenever the target directory exists it moves into the target directory, otherwise it gets renamed.

Comment: That is inconsistent. The same command should do the same thing. That means the command is ambiguous.

Comment: That's not really inconsistent because it acts consistently within context. Although I can see how it's confusing but the more I think about it, the command has to be that way in order to work for all scenarios.

Comment: I would rather say that's how it is designed and its also logical..if you use `mv` with files it does the same thing.just renaming.but with `mv` with directories It's not good to delete the whole directory with subdirectory because of one `mv` command which is not safe. so it is moved as `test1/test2`. but if you still want to acheive it write a `alias` which check whether the parameter given is directory and then do rm -rf the directory and uses the `mv` command but use it at your own risk.

Comment: I suspect your example is based on misremembering something that has happened in the past, based on "It seems that I do something like this".  If both `/hello` and `/hello2` are directories, then I've noticed that `cp /hello /hello2` is the one that's inconsistent.  Depending on what combination of trailing slashes are there, sometimes the contents of `/hello` are copied into `/hello2`, and sometimes the directory itself is copied in.

Comment: I don't remember where I saw it, but when they designed Plan 9 (sort of a successor to UNIX) they split moving from renaming commands specifically to address situations like this.

Comment: If the target is a directory, the source gets moved into it. If it is a plain file, it gets overwritten.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`mv a b` attempts to move `a` into `b` if `b` is a directory or a symlink to a directory. Otherwise, it will rename (or copy and delete if on different file systems) `a` to `b`.

To get a consistent result to move a file into a directory, you can do:

```
mv file dir/.
```

If `dir` doesn't exist, you'll get an error, and it won't rename `file` to `dir`.

`mv file dir/` would also work, but not if `file` itself is of type *directory* and `dir` itself doesn't exist.

If, on the other hand, you want to do a `rename` without having to worry if the destination file exists as a directory or not, with GNU mv, you can do:

```
mv -T file dest
```

In that case, `file` will not be moved into `dest` if `dest` is a directory. However, if both `file` and `dest` are directories and `dest` is empty, `file` will be renamed to `dest` (and the original `dest` removed). If both are directories and `dest` is non-empty, `mv -T` will complain.

Same, if `file` and `dest` are *not* directories (and that includes symlinks including symlinks to directories), `file` will be renamed to `dest` (though you will get a prompt if you don't have write permission to `dest`), and the original `dest` will be removed. There's a difference with `mv file dest` in the case where `dest` is a symlink to a directory. With `-T`, `file` is renamed to `dest`, but without `-T`, `file` is moved into the directory pointed to by `dest`.

So to sum up, after `mv -T file dest`, either `file` will have been renamed to `dest` or you'll get an error message (or a prompt). If the command succeeded, the original `dest`, if it existed beforehand will have been removed.

Comment: Your first example doesn't work for me: To make sure a file is moved into a directory I need `mv file dir/.` (with dot). Maybe it's because GNU mv has had its behavior changed since you wrote this...

Comment: @philipp2100, see edit. I suspect you're refering to the case where the source file is a directory which I hadn't thought of.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I thought it was mostly about the case where source is a directory, so my comment didn't stress that as clear as it could have, but I think your edit quite cleared things up.
However, existing targets are not a problem for me in the `target/` case: `mv a empty/` will just move `a` into `empty`, also if `empty` is a symlink, and dangling symlinks as targets will fail, although for `empty/` (unlike `empty` or `empty/.`) `mv` asks for confirmation first, which can be undesirable.

Comment: @philipp2100, yes, you're right, not sure what I was thinking. Fixed now.

Answer (score 16):

This is entirely dependent of if there was already a directory named `/hello2` already in existence or not.

If `/hello2` exists AND is a directory, then `mv` will always move `/hello` to `/hello2/hello`.

If `/hello2` does not exist, then `mv` will always rename `/hello` to `/hello2`.

If `/hello2` exists AND is a file, you will get an error, `cannot overwrite non-directory 'hello2' with directory 'hello'`.

Answer (score 3):

I tried these

```
mkdir test1
mv -v test1 test2
output:`test1' -> `test2'
mkdir test1
mv -v test2 test1
output: `test2' -> `test1/test2'
touch test2
output:mv: cannot overwrite non-directory `test2' with directory `test1'
```

hope this explains everything. `-v` is verbose mode.